# How to do localization in different languages in latest angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new in angular development. I have created a web application using angular CLI.
I want to have my web application in different languages- Hindi, Marathi and English.
I searched for it on net, I got [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) but I am not able to make it work properly.

Comment: I think you need to map your original language words with the translated language words by creating es.xlf file

Comment: Yes, I followed the above mentioned link and they have given commands to do so. But I am not able to make it work. Can you please share me the example tutorial? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `ng-xi18n` method is not working for you, there are few other ways you can do localization.

1. Use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)  library. You can find details in [README.md](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/README.md)
2. Create your own `translation` pipe by following steps in [Simple Language Translation in Angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I downloaded the project given in the above link and added the code in angular CLI project. but I am getting compliation error:

Comment: ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'd
ictionary'....